# passing object inside inner function

Tags: javascript, scope

```
function google(){
     var kevin = "hello";
     john(kevin);
}

function john(arg){
     var mark = arg;
    function yahoo(mark){
          alert(mark);   
    }

}
```

Now when i call my function `google()` why does it not it call the alert in yahoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not call `yahoo`. You need to do this:

```
function john(arg){
     var mark = arg;
    function yahoo(mark){
          alert(mark);   
    }

    yahoo(mark); // <-------
}
```

You could also refactor you code to do something like this:

```
function john(arg){
     var mark = arg;

    (function yahoo(){
          alert(mark);   
    })();
}
```

Comment: You could just pass arg if you so choose.

Comment: @Lloyd Your syntax is invalid in the refactored case. Self-executing function should be wrapped with parenthesis.

Comment: @Lloyd Still the problem remains: you use invalid syntax.

Comment: @VisioN Actually it isn't, `(function() {})();` and `(function() {}());` will work just the same.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no call of `yahoo` function inside `john`.

```
function john(arg) {
    var mark = arg;
    function yahoo(mark) {
          alert(mark);   
    }
    yahoo(mark);  // <-- call
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the function `yahoo` but never actually calling it. Try this:

```
function google(){
     var kevin = "hello";
     john(kevin);
}

function john(arg){
     var mark = arg;
     yahoo(mark);
     function yahoo(mark){
          alert(mark);   
     }    
}
```